# MAT data into Python to use in CSV - different sample rates

Tags: python, csv

I have some MAT files that I'd like to output as CSV. If I give up, I can save them as .txt, but I'd really rather know how to do this in CSV.

My problem is that I have different timestamps for different channels. I believe I have some channels as low as .5hz and some at about 10 hz. They don't seem to line up exactly, though. Someone suggested a zero-order hold (I don't understand how to execute that), but as I'm releasing this data as "unadulterated", I don't really want to adjust the timestamp.

```
channels = []

for key in matfile.keys():
    if key.startswith('CAN'):
        channels.append(str(key) + '_time')
        channels.append(key)

output = {}

for channel in channels:
    if channel.endswith('_time'):
        channel_time = channel[0:-5]       
        output[channel] = matfile[channel_time].item()[6] 
    else:
        output[channel] = matfile[channel].item()[7].item()[0]

with open(path_plus_title, 'wb') as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   writer.writerow(channels)
   writer.writerows(zip(*(output[k] for k in channels)))
```

This gives me only the channels I want, in order of channel time stamp followed by channel...but it stops writing after it reaches the end of the shortest column of data.

I'd like to fill the shorter columns with spaces or zeros or anything to keep the data straight and to make it clear that that's where the data ends. Is there maybe a column-wise way to do it that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [itertools.izip_longest()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest). The reason it is ending early is that zip ends when the first iterator ends, but izip_longest buffers the shorter iterators with default values, exactly like you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!                writer.writerows(itertools.izip_longest(*(output[k] for k in channels)))